# How to pass command options to ant with NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I'd like to build a netbeans project using ant passing a variable (-Dbuild.env=x) is this possible through NetBeans options or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't check it right now, but do you mean [this here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAntParameters)?